# How to read data from .json file in typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I have a json file in assets folder called data.json

```
{
    "response": {
        "sales_amount": 0,
        "collection_amount": 0,
        "carts_amount": 736.63,

}
}
```

I am doing like this to get data in service.ts file

```
 my_data: any;
  public getResponseData() : Promise<any> {
      if(typeof(this.my_data) === "undefined") {
            return this.http.get('assets/data.json')
            .toPromise().then(res => {

                                  this.my_data = res.json().response;
                                  return this.my_data;
                }).catch(this.handleError);
      } else {
          return Promise.resolve(this.my_data);
      }


  }
```

Here i am getting response in this.my_data,but in the component.ts file i am doing like this

```
ngOnInit(){


        this.myService.getResponseData().then(response => this.detailsdata = response);
}
```

**but here in this.detailsdata  i am not getting anything.**

and after this i want to display **sales_amount**,**collection_amount** in the **html** file.

```
<div>
     <span>sales amount</span>
</div>
```

In place of sales amount i want to display the value
how to do this.
I am very new to typescript.can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct. I just checked that in test application. What you need is just few lines of code in html file.

Please add following code to your html file.

```
<p><b>sales amount:</b> {{ detailsdata?.sales_amount }}</p>
<p><b>collection amount:</b> {{ detailsdata?.collection_amount }}</p>
<p><b>carts amount:</b> {{ detailsdata?.carts_amount }}</p>
```

By the way, your json data is invalid. Remove comma after the `carts_amount` property.

```
{
  "response": {
    "sales_amount": 6000.77,
    "collection_amount": 399.57,
    "carts_amount": 736.63
  }
}
```

Updates:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

        this.myService.getResponseData().then((value) => {
            //SUCCESS
            console.log(value);
            this.detailsdata = value;

        }, (error) => {
            //FAILURE
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you response.Actually i am trying as u suggested(<p><b>sales amount:</b> {{ detailsdata?.sales_amount }}</p>).
but i am not getting any result.
and with below code i am not getting any result in console.
ngOnInit(){
 this.myService.getResponseData().then(response => this.detailsdata = response);
cosole.log('result'+this.detailsdata)
}.
So i am in doubt whether this is correct or not.Can you please tell me this one.

Comment: Could you please put {{ detailsdata | json }} in html file and check if it shows anything. Need to check if data is actually read from json file.

Comment: @ananya your console will not print anything as the process to fetch data will run asynchronously and code to log (console.log)will be executed even before it fetches result from service. Check my updated code, which will log only after fetching the values.

Comment: ,Thanks Sangram,i am getting the result in console and getting data in html also using {{ detailsdata?.sales_amount }} this only.I tried in a new project and its working.May be in current project some css problem is there so value is not displaying.
Thank you so much Sangram for your time. :):)